# Why is 'B' matched by [a-z]?

Tags: javascript, regex

a very simple & naive question:
why this is true?

```
new RegExp('^[a-z]+$', 'i').test('B')
```

apparently 'B' is out of [a-z]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but you have the `i` parameter which tells the regex to ignore case.

From the MDN documentation for [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> ## Parameters
>
> #### pattern
>
> The text of the regular expression.
>
> #### flags
>
> If specified, flags can have any combination of the following values:
>
> ...
>
> - `i`
>
>   ignore case

Answer (score 3):

It's defining a class, which is to say `[a-z]` is symbolic of "any character, from `a` to `z`."

Regex is, by nature, case SensAtiVe as well, so `[a-z]` varies from `[A-Z]` (unless you use the `i` (case insensitive) flag, like you've demonstrated).

e.g.

```
/[a-z]/              -- Any single character, a through z
/[A-Z]/              -- Any single uppercase letter, A through Z
/[a-zA-Z]/           -- Any single upper or lowercase letter, a through z
/[a-z]/i or /[A-Z]/i -- (note the i) Any upper or lowercase letter, a through z
```

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

- The [a-z] means a character set containing characters a-z.
- The ^ is an anchor which means the set must begin with the first character of input.
- The + means you must match on one or more from the character set.
- The $ is an end anchor meaning the set must end the last character of input.
- The i means to ignore case on your input letters.

Answer (score 0):

It means any character between `a` and `z`.

As you specified the `i` flag (case insensitive), it contains also `B`.

The whole regexp checks that the string contains at least one character and that all characters are in a-z or A-Z.

You can check that `new RegExp('^[a-z]+$', 'i').test('B')` returns `true`.

Comment: He's got the `i` modifier (ignore case) toggled, so it doesn't really matter.